# linq query .ToList() to json

Tags: json, ajax, linq

I would like to display a list of photos with the name of the file from database.

I have the following query:

```
var queryList = (from media in _context.Medias
    where media.ProductId == Id
    orderby media.MediaOrder
    select new ProductMediaList
    {
    MediaName = "<div><img src='https://www.example.com/img/" + media.MediaName + "' class='img - thumbnail' style='width: 150px' /></div>"
    }).ToList();
```

In my view:

```
    $(".call_ajax").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                detaildata = data.MediaName
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                var r = "There is a problem";
                alert("Message: " + r);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Works perfectly on .FirstOrDefault() but can't have it working on .ToList()

Of course, we can have the html part in js and not in query

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Please check your browser Console for errors. Your javascript code is expecting to retrieve one object with property `MediaName` and probably that's why it works with `FirstOrDefault()`. If you use `ToList()`, this line no longer makes sense: `data.MediaName` as `data` is now an array. You have to iterate on `data` and get `MediaName` for each element in the array.

Comment: thanks @derloopkat. That'S my problem. How do I get MediaName for each element in the array?

Comment: You can do a simple `forEach()` or `for` loop. Google for syntax.

Comment: Thanks @derloopkat. When I do                         for (var m in data)
                        {
                            detaildata = detaildata + data[m];
                        }
I get [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]